# What do you call this type of property?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the below code, what do you call that kind of property?

```
public interface IValue<T>
{
    T Value { get; }
}

public class BaseValue<T> : IValue<T>
{
    T IValue<T>.Value { get; } // What would you call this kind of property?
}
```

Comment: It's an explicitly implemented interface declared generic property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: @Enigmativity ...readonly autoproperty

Comment: Or more precisely its an private explicit readonly auto implemented generic property

Comment: Thanks much.  I am trying to name my test case and had no clue what to call it :)